# include if value in array defined on included file

Tags: php, arrays, include

I want to check if the page name is a value in an array defined on the included file and, if so, include it.

```
<?php

// parent page that includes the files

$pageLabel = 'three';

if (in_array('pageLabel', $multicats)) {
    include $filename;
}

?>


<?php

// example for a file to be included

$multicats = array('one', 'three', 'five');
$filename = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

echo 'Hello World of one, three and five';

?>
```

However an error says it expects $multicats to be an array, which it is, meaning it doesn't check the included file for it.

What to do?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That makes not much sense to check if a value is in an array which is in a file which you only want to include if the value is in the array

Comment: are you including the file which has the array defined in ?

Comment: yes! each file in a directory has an array. If one of the values in that array matches the variable defined on a parent-page it should be included.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have array of multicats somewhere in parent page before condition. If you have it in included file, it's init after using in condition. Or you can check if it exist with `isset`, as Captain Crunch said.

Note: in condition `in_array` you have string `'pageLabel'` and not var `$pageLabel`, is it correct?

Answer (score -1):

first, you should pass: $pageLabel var, and not 'pageLabel' string (see line 4 in your code).

second, i advise you use "isset":

```
if ( isset($multicats) && isset($multicats[$pageLabel]) && isset($filename) ) 
    include $filename;
```